# Strange Shadow on Border with :after

Tags: css

Having an issue in FF6 where I am seeing a shadow on border when an adjoining border is set to transparent.

```
.ux-menu-item.selected { background-color: #fb4615 }
.ux-menu-item.selected:after { content:""; width: 0; height: 0; background-color: transparent; border-left: 62.5px solid transparent; border-top: 20px solid yellow; border-right: 62.5px solid white; position: absolute; }
```

[image: Selected menu item]

I am realizing this happens even with white. Seems the original image I posted the yellow you could not see the blur.

```
.ux-menu-item.selected:after { content:""; width: 0; height: 0; background-color: transparent; border-left: 62.5px solid white; border-top: 20px solid orange; border-right: 62.5px solid white; position: absolute; }
```

[image: Black arrow]

Comment: Seems FF blurs the edges when the corners are farther from 90 degrees.

Comment: What is `.5px`? I don't think you can really display a half pixel. Maybe it's not related, but I believe the browser can choose to round up or down.

Comment: The containing box is 125 pixels.

Comment: @Madmartigan I actually do. With something like this I am either under or over a pixel.

Comment: Deleted my comment after reading the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative0) stating `pixels; 1px is equal to 1/96th of 1in` - so .5px could actually mean something, but of course not literally.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox creates these artifacts when using this CSS trick. Setting the other borders to the color of your background (white, in this case) instead of transparent fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you have a source or reference for this?